# Getting an error when running php artisan generate command in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

when I try to run:

```
php artisan generate:migration create_users_table
```

I get this error:

```
[ErrorException]
file_put_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\nldb.dev/database/migrations/2014_09_10
_013940_create_users_table.php): failed to open stream: No such file or di
rectory
```

I have ran composer install/update, I created the project using composer, etc.

I am on Win 7 using xampp and virtual hosts. Thanks for any suggestions you can give me.

Please note for some reason it uses "nldb.dev/database" instead of nldb.dev/app/database. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried checking if the folder C:\xampp\htdocs\nldb.dev/database/migrations/ exists, and that its parent directories exists? For your second question, is your webroot configured to be blahblah/nldb.dev/public/ ? It appears that Laravel thinks that your app folder is located in nldb.dev.

Comment: @Rob The folder is not supposed to exist in the location, iot's supposed to be in app/databe/... The webroot is c:\xampp\htdocs\ with nlccdb.dev as a folder. I have no idea why laravel is not looking for the app folder before the database folder.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Jeffery Way's generator and laravel's version 4.2. The problem may be with the configurations of the files and targeted directories to make files the packages points to.

If so go to the `vendor/way/generators/src/config/config.php` location and make the following changes.

[image]

Comment: You helped me a lot thanks! No idea why these pathes were wrong